# write/generate xml from the given xml schema

Tags: xml

I have to send data to some external service in xml format.
They have provided xml schema as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.
w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="TRANSACTION">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="LOGIN">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="USERID" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="PASSWORD" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="TRANID" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="CUSTOMER">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="CUSTSSN" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
<xs:element name="CUSTFNAME" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="CUSTLNAME" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="CUSTADDRESS" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="CUSTCITY" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="CUSTSTATE" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="CUSTZIP" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
<xs:element name="CUSTHOMEPHONE" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
<xs:element name="CUSTMOBILEPHONE" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
<xs:element name="CUSTEMAIL" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Based on above schema, how should I write my xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general XSD describes a set of documents which are conformant with a schema. For most schemas there are many different documents which are valid against the schema. In your case the schema prescribes everything expect the content of the strings, so something like:

```
    <TRANSACTION>
        <LOGIN>
            <USERID>uu</USERID>
            <PASSWORD>pp</PASSWORD>
        </LOGIN>
 <!-- omitted some of body -->
        <CUSTOMER>
            <CUSTSSN>123</CUSTSSN>
            <CUSTFNAME>Cust</CUSTFNAME>
  <!-- omitted-->
        </CUSTOMER>
    </TRANSACTION>
```

would do - you should be able to fill in the bits I have left out

Comment: Do I need to include the namsespace line in my xml, <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.
w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

Comment: @tecks No. They haven't defined a namespace (the XSD namespace defines the schema not the document)